# Get the children table data of $(this), which is the table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function

```
$("#names tbody tr").click(#something here);
```

and I was wondering. Since I'm already "inside" the tr of the table, from here how do I go through each individual td using the this object?

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-67349879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$("#names tbody tr").click(function(){
    $(this).children('td').each(function(index, element){
         //here are your td 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('td').each( function(){
// do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#names tbody tr").click(function(){
   $(this).find('td').each(function(){
      alert($(this).html());
   });
 });
```

will output the content of each TD in the row in turn

```
 Note the first "this" refers to the <tr> element, the second to the <td> element since it occurs within the .each() function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way:

```
$('td', this)
```